# Creating a dataclass that generates an instance of another class as a default attribute. How can I satisfy this Pylint warning?

Tags: python, pylint, python-dataclasses

Consider this python script

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass



@dataclass
class ClassB:
    class_a: ClassA = field(default_factory=lambda: ClassA())
```

Pylint warns that the [lambda might not be necessary](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/unnecessary-lambda.html). Is there a cleaner alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like indeed it isn't, since all it does is returns an instance of a `ClassA` when it's called.

What about:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        pass



@dataclass
class ClassB:
    class_a: ClassA = field(default_factory=ClassA)
```

According to docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field  `default_factory` needs a 0 argument callable, which your class seems to be, so it should be just fine.

EDIT:
After the comments exchange I think we've got some misunderstanding about `lambdas`, `functions`, `callables` and a bunch of other things.
Please take a look at the example below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

# Named function
def give_me_class_A_instance():
    return A()

@dataclass
class B1:
    class_a: ClassA = field(default_factory=give_me_class_A_instance)

# Lambda
lambda_equivalent = lambda: A()

@dataclass
class B2:
    class_a: ClassA = field(default_factory=lambda_equivalent)

# No function at all
@dataclass
class B3:
    class_a: ClassA = field(default_factory=A)
```

All 3 `B1`, `B2` and `B3` are the same from the point of view their instantiation. Lambda is no different than a "regular function" and there is no need to distinguish them at all (in this case). Most often they (lambdas) are passed as "callbacks" when using e.g. sorting, filtering or this kind of initialization mechanisms, there is nothing which prevents you from using a regular functions there though or naming a lambda (assigning it to a label/variable).

And also please keep in mind, that `lambda: A` and `lambda: A()` are not the same:

```
class A: pass

a_alias = lambda: A
a_instance = lambda: A()

a_alias() # <class '__main__.A'> <- "reference" to class A 
a_alias()() # A() <- an instance of class A

a_instance() # A() <- an instance of class A
```

Comment: Are these two lines equivalent: class_a = ClassA() , class_a = lambda: ClassA ?

Comment: Not even close, the 1st one assigns instance of `ClassA` to `class_a` label ("variable" if you will, which is a bad name in python though), the 2nd one assigns a function (unnamed, because it's a `lambda`, but that doesn't matter actually). But I think this is **NOT** what `default_factory` does, is it? For the lack of a better word I'd say default factory uses what you give it as a "callback" when it's instantiating the instance of a `classB` (again this is not a very precise explanation).